# Air for iOS SDK higher as 14, gives strange stage behavior

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air, screen-size, stage

I run yesterday into the following bug, without finding a solution at the moment.

I created an app a year ago with Air for iOS SDK 14. Everything is fine, until I wanted to update it this year compiling it with Air 17.

In this new Build, I have some heavy problems with the stage size. All my calculated alignments are wrong It looks like something has changed concerning, how stage width/height and/or screensize is handled and calculated by Air.

Has anyone a clue what has changed? I browsed the changelogs, but got no hint.

The problem occurs with every SDK higher than 14.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Publishing for what?

Comment: @Vesper The Code is always the same. The only difference is, I compile it via the Flash IDE with Air 14, and then I compile with Air 17, and everything goes awkward.

Comment: @BotMaster I'm publishing for iOS, tested it on the iPhone 5 and iPhone 6, always the same problem.

Comment: what I can tell you is that all my apps were updated to 16, 17 and recently 18 and they have never produced any wrong sizing. Saying the sizing is wrong is also way too vague for anyone to figure anything, post screnshots.

Comment: It looks, like Capabilities.screenResolutionY has changed, it gives me different values for Air14 and Air18.